# Theta approaching infinity in a negative binomial glm, what to do next?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution

I am performing a negative binomial glm in R using `glm.nb` from the MASS package. I am using this over poisson as my data is over dispersed (0.7) and the mean (0.754) and variance (1.018) are not equal.

I am however encountering errors that indicate theta in trending towards infinity:

```
    glm.nb(count ~ origin + sample + type, data = glm_df)
Warning messages:
1: In theta.ml(Y, mu, sum(w), w, limit = control$maxit, trace = control$trace >  :
  iteration limit reached
2: In theta.ml(Y, mu, sum(w), w, limit = control$maxit, trace = control$trace >  :
  iteration limit reached
```

I believe I can use `glm(formula, data, family = negative.binomial(theta))` but am unsure how to calculate the theta to use.

Would a more sensible option be to use a Hurdle model?

EDIT: histagram of the count

[image: histogram of count]

Subset of the dataframe can be found here: https://pastebin.com/sDfcQMiJ

Comment: most likely you showed the variance and mean of count, and it can be overdispersed because you did not account for other factors, like the ones you are regressing against.

Comment: you can try this glm(count ~ origin + sample + type,data=glm_df,family=quasipoisson), see what is the dispersion, or if the terms can be properly estimated. I suspect either you have a lot of zeros, or because your data cannot support this level of complexity

Comment: The model is zero inflated yes, that is another reason why I though Hurdle might be best to use.

Comment: How should I go about providing a huge dataframe? What information would you like to know about the model? It is biological question so I am not sure what info would help you here.

Comment: You can make a histogram of the counts, and include that? We can see how much zeros there are. You can of course just use pscl and fit a zero-inflated poisson first, and see how the results look. For the zero inflated part, suggest you fit a intercept only model first to begin with

Comment: Back to the point of providing a huge data.frame, I assume we don't need the whole data to see the zero-inflation. A small portion should be enough to illustrate the problem. If you use dput(<subset>) you can paste it as part of the post. It takes time and effort and make a good question, and I can assure you, you get better answers this way

Comment: @StupidWolf I hav added a histogram. I used the check `check_zeroinflation()` from the `performance` package and is said it was zero inflated. However when using a zero inflated model I get `system is computationally singular` warnings. Also added a bit of the dataframe: https://pastebin.com/sDfcQMiJ

Comment: It means some of the terms in your model cannot be estimated. For example are there groups with only 1 non zeros ? Can you check which one is it, fit this ``` glm(count ~ origin + sample + type,data=glm_df,family=quasipoisson)``` , you will see which coefficients cannot be estimated

Comment: @StupidWolf There is indeed one coefficient in `type`(NRPS) that appears is not being estimated. However looking at that it has nine 0s. Am I looking the output wrong maybe? The intercept is being taken as a value from origin if I understand correctly so that would not be where the missing `type` is?